# Angular form select options vs radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

I have a working form select like this in angularjs.

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct" 
    ng-options="product as product.text for product in products">
</select>
```

I want to change this to radio buttons, since there are only two options in products. The UI will improve from it. The output from above are select options with `value=0` and `value=1`.

I tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <input id="{{product.productId}}" type="radio" 
         name="BlahBlah" ng-value="{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedProduct" required />
    <label for="{{product.productId}}">
        {{product.text}}
    </label>
</div>
```

The `$index` renders `value=0` and `value=1` for the radio buttons, just like the select options. But it doesn't work. The data is not picked up and passed along by the controller. I would prefer not to rewrite things in the controller, if possible.

I thought this would be super-easy :-/
How can I move forward here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select's ng-model is a product object, not 0 or 1. The equivalent would just be

```
<input type="radio" name="BlahBlah" ng-value="product" ng-model="selectedProduct" />
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OLfcAwv4wEX2K3mAxBxK?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for this demo! Very interesting. In your demo both select and the radios are linked – they update each other. When I try changing `ng-value` to `product`, the select will indeed update the radios, but not the other way around. And using radio buttons still won't pass the correct data to the next step. But the select will. I am so confused right now. Greatful for all tips.

Comment: That's because you used `selectedProduct` as your ng-model. Never do that. Always have a dot in your ng-model. ng-repeat defines its own scope, and your radios are inside an ng-repeat. So selecting a radio sets the `selectedProduct`in the scope of the ng-repeat, not in the scope of the controller. Do just like me, and define a model object in your controller. And use `model.selectedProduct` as your ng-model.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much! 